# EXCEL Data Validation ISBLANK not working

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a problem with data validation in EXCEL. I try to add this validation to the range of cells:

```
   With zakres.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=IF(ISBLANK($" & _
        kolumna_litera(kol_Data_oceny_formalnej) _
        & "3),FALSE,status_status_RK)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Nieprawidłowy status!"
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "Wybierz poprawny status z listy rozwijanej!"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

kolumna_litera - stands for function returning column letter (String); kol_Data_oceny_formalnej - stands for number of column (Long); status_status_RK - stands for named range with list of values;

The problem is when cell kolumna_litera&3 is empty. Then error 1004 occurs - in the line Validation.Add. When this cell is filled, there is no error. I have no idea why this happens. Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: Which error do you get, on which line?  Also, "not working" is very vague, please provide more details about what you have, what you need to have in the end, what you've tried and what's happening.

Comment: in the third line - one with the validation.add

Comment: Thanks - please [edit] your question to clarify that, as well as my other questions about your question.  Also, see "[ask]" as well as **how to create a [mcve]**. More tips [**here**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) from the site's top user.

Comment: *kolumna_litera - stands for function returning collumn letter (String)*.  Also, you have `ISBLANK($" & _
        kolumna_litera(kol_Data_oceny_formalnej) _
        & "3)` , so you concatenate `kolumna_litera` with a 3 always. `IsBlank` needs a reference to a range, not just a number. When `kolumna_litera` is empty, `IsBlank` try to checks a range `3` and that maybe could be causing your error with the function. Maybe you should consider checking first if `kolumna_litera` is empty before trying to add the data validation?

Comment: Shouldin't it be .IgnoreBlank = False ?

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns by checking the validation first You mean add some extra formula? Can You give me a hint how to make this?

Comment: one more thing, I just tried to add data validation to cell, I've typed something like this: `=JEŻELI(CZY.PUSTA($AE3);FAŁSZ;status_status_RK)` in english it wil be `=IF(ISBLANK($AE3),FALSE,status_status_RK)`  I get the message: List must be a delimited list, or a reference to a single row or column. List is a named range in one column

Comment: Something like `If kolumna_litera <> "" Then.... 'all the validation part`. It's just an idea, but you should test it. Also, think about a solution when `kolumna_litera = ""` and apply it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I Found the solution. The problem was with the `FALSE` statement in the formula. When cell `kolumna_litera(kol_Data_oceny_formalnej) & "3`was empty Excel could not find the list with data - and could not use the `FALSE` statement. So I added a named range containing one empty cell and replaced this with the name of this range (called PUSTA). The code looks like that now:

```
    With zakres.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=IF(ISBLANK($" & kolumna_litera(kol_Data_wpływu_RK) & "3),PUSTA,status_status_RK)"
    .IgnoreBlank = False
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Nieprawidłowy status!"
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "Wybierz poprawny status z listy rozwijanej! Lista ze statusami pojawi się jeśli wpisana została data z wpływem RK."
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
    End With
```

So far It works, hope that this was the problem.